# Valor en label nulo o 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Cómo hacer para que si (por ejemplo en dos casillas para realizar una operación) en una de las casillas text no has introducido ningún valor, no se cierre la aplicación.

y para casillas label?

```
@IBOutlet weak var N1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var N2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var N3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var P1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var P2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var P3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var F1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var F2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var F3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var res1: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

       @IBAction func tot(_ sender: Any) {


 let n1 = Double(N1.text!)
 let p1 = Double(P1.text!)
   let f1 = Double(n1! * p1! / 100)

    F1.text = "\(f1)"



    let n2 = Double(N2.text!)
    let p2 = Double(P2.text!)
    let f2 = Double(n2! * p2! / 100)

    F2.text = "\(f2)"


    let n3 = Double(N3.text!)
    let p3 = Double(P3.text!)
    let f3 = Double(n3! * p3! / 100)

    F3.text = "\(f3)"


    guard let a = Double(F1.text!), let b = Double(F2.text!), let c = Double(F3.text!) else
    {
        return
    }

    let suma = a + b + c
    self.res1.text = String(suma)


       }
```

}

Comment: ¿Cual es el código que tienes actualmente?

Comment: Lo he colocado en la pregunta. La duda en este código es que si no meto un valor dentro de esas casillas N(123) / P(123) . se me cierra el programa. Y no se como hacer para las casillas que no tengan valores, directamente no ejecuten la operación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes usar el operador de coalescencia `??`. Dicho operador, comprueba si un opcional tiene valor, o por el contrario si es `nil`. Y en este último caso, le asigna el valor que pones a su derecha.

así `let var1 = N1.text ?? "default"` asignará a `var1` el valor de N1, y si éste fuera `nil`, le asignaría `"default"`

De este modo:

```
@IBAction func tot(_ sender: Any) {


   let n1 = Double(N1.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
   let p1 = Double(P1.text ?? "") ?? 0.0

   let f1 = Double(n1 * p1 / 100)

   F1.text = "\(f1)"


   let n2 = Double(N2.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
   let p2 = Double(P2.text ?? "") ?? 0.0

   let f2 = Double(n2 * p2! / 100)

   F2.text = "\(f2)"


   let n3 = Double(N3.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
   let p3 = Double(P3.text ?? "") ?? 0.0

   let f3 = Double(n3 * p3 / 100)

   F3.text = "\(f3)"


   let suma = f1 + f2 + f3
   self.res1.text = String(suma)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hola, intenta esto nuevamente y confirma si te funciona**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var F1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var F2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var F3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rest: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var N1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var N2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var N3: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var P1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P3: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func presionarBoton(_ sender: Any) {

        if let n1 = Double(N1.text!), let n2 = Double(N2.text!), let n3 = Double(N3.text!), let p1 =  Double(P1.text!), let p2 = Double(P2.text!), let p3 = Double(P3.text!){

            let f1 = Double(n1 * p1 / 100)
            F1.text = String(f1)

            let f2 = Double(n2 * p2 / 100)
            F2.text = String(f2)

            let f3 = Double(n3 * p3 / 100)
            F3.text = String(f3)


        }else {
            print("Llene todos los campos")
            self.F1.text = ""
            self.F2.text = ""
            self.F3.text = ""
            self.rest.text = ""
        }

        guard let a = Double(F1.text!), let b = Double(F2.text!), let c = Double(F3.text!) else {
            return
        }

        let suma = a + b + c
        self.rest.text = String(suma)

    }

}
```

**Te recomiendo que veas estos cursos básicos**

https://www.udacity.com/course/learn-swift-programming-syntax--ud902

**Y También leas esta documentación**
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html